# Removing nth element from an array and reindex it

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => '13-Nov'
    [1] => 'PUJA SUNUWAR'
    [2] => '13-Nov'
    [3] => '...301303'
    [4] => 'TT1331600004\DLG'
    [5] => '-10000.00'
    [6] => '0'
    [7] => '90000.00'
)
```

I need to remove 4th item of array and save it as

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => '13-Nov'
        [1] => 'PUJA SUNUWAR'
        [2] => '13-Nov'
        [3] => 'TT1331600004\DLG'
        [4] => '-10000.00'
        [5] => '0'
        [6] => '90000.00'
    )
```

i don't want to iterate over each elements of array. Is there any one shot function like `array_pop` to remove nth element of array?

Comment: What's wrong with this `unset($array[2]);` ? Or you can create a function, that loops through the array and creates a new one w/out the unnecessary value.

Comment: unset on its own will not reindex the arrays.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use `array_splice($array, 3, 1);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

Answer (score 1):

Is this a 2d-array? If so:

No, there is no built in function to do this. You could use ´array_walk´ with a custom callback but I doubt it would be faster than a simple foreach.

Else (if normal array):

```
unset( $aData[3] );

$aData = array_values( $aData );
```

Wich is faster then array_splice.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, there is no build in function for that. 
You should use `unset` if you dont need to care about array indexing and `array_values` if should.

Also you should use [`value reference`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871373/php-reference-objects-in-foreach-loop) while array iterating to prevent internal array copyng while values modification. If dont, it can be one of perfomance break down reasons.

```
foreach ($yourDataSet as &$value) {
    unset($value[2]); 
    //$value = array_values($value);
}
```

You shouldt use `array_splice` becouse of [perfomance reasons](http://www.svachon.com/blog/benchmark-php-array_splice-vs-unset-array_values/).

p.s. Also you could check [phpbench](http://www.phpbench.com/) for perfomance test about different types of array iteration.